# Returning multiple lines from a data structure

Tags: python

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for element in lst:
    return ("element: {}".format(element))
```

Outcome: 
element: 1

Wanted outcome:
element: 1 
element: 2 
element: 3 
element: 4

I can do this with a simple print statement but is this possible with a return statement instead?

thank you

Comment: you want the returned as a string or an array of strings?

Comment: Return an array of strings instead.

Comment: `return` immediately stop function execution and return result you passed to this expression, so your `for` loop will have just single iteration.

Comment: You could convert you function to a generator function. Then you can iterate on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it as follows.

```
def reformat(lst):
    return '\n'.join("element: {}".format(element) for element in lst)
```

Comment: It's bad habit to mix different quotes ;-)

Comment: this is great. is this considered list comprehension ?

Comment: @user145682, it's [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression).

Comment: Yes, it is a list comprehension.

Comment: @KateMelnykova, it is not.

Comment: Wow, @OlvinRoght, thanks for pointing me out a new resource. Always happy to learn something new.

Comment: @KateMelnykova, you're welcome. Btw, using list comprehension there has sense cause passing *list comprehension* int `str.join()` (surprisingly) faster than *generator expression* in most cases.